# How to blend Decal on Glass material

Tags: texturing

I made Decal in Substance painter and exported it to Blender. Now I want this decal to be like real full decal on glass. I made glass in Blender with Transparent BSDF and mixed in mix shader to mix them together.

But problem is with this fax that it only can be fully transparent but you won't see decal, or, to be not transparent at all but be full color decal. What is the right way to have fully transparent material with full color decal on it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing happens. Do I need to tweak any other node?

Comment: What happens if you plug the Alpha from the texture to the Mix shader Fac?

Comment: @Radoon, please pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded file. Be free to check and try!

Comment: you didn't pack your texture, go to File > External Data > Pack all into .blend and upload it again

Comment: Sorry-now it should be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug the *Image Texture* into the *Principled BSDF*, you're just coloring the glass material.

You can mix the *Glass* node (or *Principled BSDF* is this is the node you use to do the glass) and the *Image Texture > Diffuse* in a *Mix Shader* with the *Texture*'s alpha as factor:

[image]